# How to use the time-sampled data(50 samples/Minute) as input for classifying the output

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series, multiclass-classification

I am working on a classification problem and the data I have is a time sampled data(50 samples/Minute).

```
  A1       A2     A3        A4     A5      A6       Time               OUTPUT
0.1808  -1.9547 1.0487  -0.1018 -0.2402 -0.216  2018-03-22 10:53:27:009 Walk
0.1808  -1.9547 1.0487  -0.1018 -0.2402 -0.216  2018-03-22 10:53:27:029 
0.1808  -1.9547 1.0487  0.0136  -0.2096 0.6761  2018-03-22 10:53:27:049 
1.0641  -1.1054 -1.7732 0.0136  -0.2096 0.6761  2018-03-22 10:53:27:069 
1.0641  -1.1054 -1.7732 0.0136  -0.2096 0.6761  2018-03-22 10:53:27:089 
1.0641  -1.1054 -1.7732 0.0136  -0.2096 0.6761  2018-03-22 10:53:27:109 
1.0641  -1.1054 -1.7732 0.0136  -0.2096 0.6761  2018-03-22 10:53:27:130 
1.0641  -1.1054 -1.7732 0.0136  -0.2096 0.6761  2018-03-22 10:53:27:149 
-0.1162 -1.462  -0.2147 -0.3992 -0.2146 0.4831  2018-03-22 10:53:27:169 
-0.1162 -1.462  -0.2147 -0.3992 -0.2146 0.4831  2018-03-22 10:53:27:189 
-0.1162 -1.462  -0.2147 -0.3992 -0.2146 0.4831  2018-03-22 10:53:27:209 
-0.1162 -1.462  -0.2147 -0.3992 -0.2146 0.4831  2018-03-22 10:53:27:229 
-0.1162 -1.462  -0.2147 -0.3992 -0.2146 0.4831  2018-03-22 10:53:27:249 
-2.6265 -1.1069 1.0123  -0.4758 -0.1737 0.4346  2018-03-22 10:53:27:269 
-2.6265 -1.1069 1.0123  -0.4758 -0.1737 0.4346  2018-03-22 10:53:27:289 
-2.6265 -1.1069 1.0123  -0.4758 -0.1737 0.4346  2018-03-22 10:53:27:309 
-2.6265 -1.1069 1.0123  -0.4758 -0.1737 0.4346  2018-03-22 10:53:27:329 
-2.6265 -1.1069 1.0123  -0.4758 -0.1737 0.4346  2018-03-22 10:53:27:349 
-1.7241 -1.0679 0.176   -0.4758 -0.1737 0.4346  2018-03-22 10:53:27:369 
-1.7241 -1.0679 0.176   0.2784  -0.1321 0.9571  2018-03-22 10:53:27:389 
-1.7241 -1.0679 0.176   0.2784  -0.1321 0.9571  2018-03-22 10:53:27:409 
-1.7241 -1.0679 0.176   0.2784  -0.1321 0.9571  2018-03-22 10:53:27:429 
-1.7241 -1.0679 0.176   0.2784  -0.1321 0.9571  2018-03-22 10:53:27:449 
-5.888  -0.4203 -0.4726 0.2784  -0.1321 0.9571  2018-03-22 10:53:27:469 
-5.888  -0.4203 -0.4726 0.4476  -0.2071 1.3086  2018-03-22 10:53:27:490 
-5.888  -0.4203 -0.4726 0.4476  -0.2071 1.3086  2018-03-22 10:53:27:509 
-5.888  -0.4203 -0.4726 0.4476  -0.2071 1.3086  2018-03-22 10:53:27:529 
-5.888  -0.4203 -0.4726 0.4476  -0.2071 1.3086  2018-03-22 10:53:27:549 
-1.3918 -1.7927 0.0591  0.4476  -0.2071 1.3086  2018-03-22 10:53:27:569 
-1.3918 -1.7927 0.0591  0.4476  -0.2071 1.3086  2018-03-22 10:53:27:589 
-1.3918 -1.7927 0.0591  0.6781  -0.4683 2.3528  2018-03-22 10:53:27:609 
-1.3918 -1.7927 0.0591  0.6781  -0.4683 2.3528  2018-03-22 10:53:27:629 
-1.3918 -1.7927 0.0591  0.6781  -0.4683 2.3528  2018-03-22 10:53:27:649 
 1.048  -2.1588 -1.3306 0.6781  -0.4683 2.3528  2018-03-22 10:53:27:669 
 1.048  -2.1588 -1.3306 0.6781  -0.4683 2.3528  2018-03-22 10:53:27:689 
 1.048  -2.1588 -1.3306 -1.0803 0.6924  -0.0053 2018-03-22 10:53:27:709 
 1.048  -2.1588 -1.3306 -1.0803 0.6924  -0.0053 2018-03-22 10:53:27:729 
 1.048  -2.1588 -1.3306 -1.0803 0.6924  -0.0053 2018-03-22 10:53:27:749 
 0.209  -0.2444 0.2241  -1.0803 0.6924  -0.0053 2018-03-22 10:53:27:769 
 0.209  -0.2444 0.2241  -1.0803 0.6924  -0.0053 2018-03-22 10:53:27:789 
 0.209  -0.2444 0.2241  -1.0803 0.6924  -0.0053 2018-03-22 10:53:27:809 
 0.209  -0.2444 0.2241  -0.8075 1.0533  -0.4522 2018-03-22 10:53:27:829 
 0.209  -0.2444 0.2241  -0.8075 1.0533  -0.4522 2018-03-22 10:53:27:849 
-1.1067 0.5311  4.2524  -0.8075 1.0533  -0.4522 2018-03-22 10:53:27:869 
-1.1067 0.5311  4.2524  -0.8075 1.0533  -0.4522 2018-03-22 10:53:27:889 
-1.1067 0.5311  4.2524  -0.8075 1.0533  -0.4522 2018-03-22 10:53:27:909 
-1.1067 0.5311  4.2524  -0.8075 1.0533  -0.4522 2018-03-22 10:53:27:929 
-1.1067 0.5311  4.2524  0.3808  0.5637  -0.2897 2018-03-22 10:53:27:949 
-1.3545 -0.0789 1.5372  0.3808  0.5637  -0.2897 2018-03-22 10:53:27:969 
-1.3545 -0.0789 1.5372  0.3808  0.5637  -0.2897 2018-03-22 10:53:27:989 
-1.3545 -0.0789 1.5372  0.3808  0.5637  -0.2897 2018-03-22 10:53:28:009 Run
-1.3545 -0.0789 1.5372  0.3808  0.5637  -0.2897 2018-03-22 10:53:28:029 
-1.3545 -0.0789 1.5372  0.3808  0.5637  -0.2897 2018-03-22 10:53:28:049 
 2.1886 -3.0297 -0.0356 1.453   -0.7246 1.5865  2018-03-22 10:53:28:069 
 2.1886 -3.0297 -0.0356 1.453   -0.7246 1.5865  2018-03-22 10:53:28:089 
 2.1886 -3.0297 -0.0356 1.453   -0.7246 1.5865  2018-03-22 10:53:28:109 
 2.1886 -3.0297 -0.0356 1.453   -0.7246 1.5865  2018-03-22 10:53:28:129 
 2.1886 -3.0297 -0.0356 1.453   -0.7246 1.5865  2018-03-22 10:53:28:149 
 2.4449 -2.6882 1.2072  1.453   -0.7246 1.5865  2018-03-22 10:53:28:169 
 2.4449 -2.6882 1.2072  -0.8857 1.3342  -1.6148 2018-03-22 10:53:28:189 
 2.4449 -2.6882 1.2072  -0.8857 1.3342  -1.6148 2018-03-22 10:53:28:209 
 2.4449 -2.6882 1.2072  -0.8857 1.3342  -1.6148 2018-03-22 10:53:28:229 
 2.4449 -2.6882 1.2072  -0.8857 1.3342  -1.6148 2018-03-22 10:53:28:249 
-1.3642 1.8139  1.3246  -0.8857 1.3342  -1.6148 2018-03-22 10:53:28:269 
-1.3642 1.8139  1.3246  -0.3441 0.2811  -0.2783 2018-03-22 10:53:28:289 
-1.3642 1.8139  1.3246  -0.3441 0.2811  -0.2783 2018-03-22 10:53:28:309 
-1.3642 1.8139  1.3246  -0.3441 0.2811  -0.2783 2018-03-22 10:53:28:330 
-1.3642 1.8139  1.3246  -0.3441 0.2811  -0.2783 2018-03-22 10:53:28:349
```

I need to classify whether it is a walk or run for each set of 50 samples

Any idea/suggestion on how to deal with this problem or how to take these 50 samples as Input and map it to single output and then train the model, or is there any other way I could use or an algorithm that could deal with such kind of problems?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the meaning of the variables?

Comment: A1 - Accelerometer X(m/s²) , A2 - Accelerometer Y(m/s²) , A3 - Accelerometer Z(m/s²) , A4- GYROSCOPE X (rad/s), A5 - GYROSCOPE Y (rad/s), A6- GYROSCOPE Z (rad/s), Time - Timestamp when the data is generated.

Answer (score 2):

Try with LSTM-RNN for sequence classification, which is your case.

This is a [very good tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/).

Comment: Thanks @pcko1. Did not think of using Deep Learning to solve this. Thought it would be possible to solve using traditional ML. Will check the tutorial and try to apply it in my problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

My idea for your data is the following, and it is based on building a classic ML classification problem.

To address it as a classification problem, we need to create features. This is my recommendation for creating features: if we are running, then the accelerometers are going to have higher values. For this reason, I would use, for every walk/run, the maximum of the absolute values of the accelerometers as features.

If this works, I would forget about the gyroscopic data. If I *had to* use it, I would take their variances as a feature, because perhaps there is more rotation when running than when walking. However, by using the accelerometer feature I think it should be enough, and a logistic regresion model should work.

Comment: You mean, I need to take the maximum value of accelerometer for each set of 50 samples and then use that from doing the classification?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant

Comment: Sure David. Will try this and see if I am getting good results :) Thanks!

Comment: And, of course, you can try with other transformations, as the variance, the mean...

Comment: Yea, Will take max, min, mean and variance and use it for classification.